# How to start railo service in background on the Docker

Tags: service, docker, railo

My name Trang,
I have created Docker image on https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/trangunghoa/railo-mysql/
It is run ok.
Now I created Dockerfile but I can't start automatic Railo service. Please help me.
I have start by some commands at shell script:

```
exec /opt/railo/railo_ctl start
exec /opt/railo/railo_ctl start -D FOREGROUND
service railo_ctl restart
exec service railo_ctl restart
```

No command it work.

Comment: Could you detail a bit more what you want to do, and how to reproduce  your problem ?

Comment: Thanks Regan has replied. I have pushed my Dockerfile on https://github.com/trangunghoa/docker_build

Comment: I have changed repository is https://github.com/trangunghoa/railo-docker

Comment: I want alter run command:
`docker build -t railo-docker https://github.com/trangunghoa/railo-docker.git` 
and 
`docker run -d -p 80:80 railo-docker` 

container will auto start railo service

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked inside your Dockerfile and identified the problem.

You can only use one CMD inside a Dockerfile. (if you use multiple CMD the old one will override) More info : https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd

You need to know that Docker isn't made for running multiple process without a little bit of help. I suggest using supervisord : https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

You can't use RUN service inside a Dockerfile, the reason is simple the command service will be executed and start a daemon, then notify the execution was successful. The temporary container will be killed (and the daemon too) and after that the change will be committed.

What your Dockerfile should look like :

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Trang Lee <trangunghoa@gmail.com>, Seta International Vietnam(info@setacinq.vn)

#Install base packages
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless
RUN apt-get install -y tomcat7 tomcat7-admin apache2 libapache2-mod-jk
RUN apt-get purge -y openjdk-6-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao openjdk-6-jre-lib icedtea-6-jre-jamvm
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor 

# config to enable .htaccess
ADD apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

# start service 
ADD start-apache2.sh /start-apache2.sh
ADD railo.sh /railo.sh
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /*.sh
#RUN sudo service apache2 start


# install railo
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget http://www.getrailo.org/railo/remote/download42/4.2.1.000/tomcat/linux/railo-4.2.1.000-pl2-linux-x64-installer.run

RUN chmod -R 744 railo-4.2.1.000-pl2-linux-x64-installer.run
RUN ./railo-4.2.1.000-pl2-linux-x64-installer.run --mode unattended --railopass “123456”

# remove railo setup
#RUN rm -rf railo-4.2.1.000-pl2-linux-x64-installer.run

#RUN sudo service railo_ctl start

RUN mkdir -p /etc/service/railo
ADD start-railo.sh /etc/service/railo/run
RUN chmod 755 /etc/service/railo/run


# EXPOSE <port>
EXPOSE 80 8888

#CMD ["/railo.sh"]
#CMD ["/start-apache2.sh"]

# Supervisord configuration
RUN mkdir /var/log/supervisor
ADD ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

With your supervisord.conf file looking something like that :

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"

[program:railo]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec /opt/railo/railo_ctl start -D FOREGROUND"
```